# How to add index to constructed object?

Tags: javascript

On (document).ready im would like to dynamically generate elements inside a certain parent-element. Lets call them "Candles".

Each "Candle" needs different properties for backgroundImage and color depending on their index().

After creating the page, these attributes need to be changeable via the interface. So its important to save the properties of the "candles" independent from each other.

Thats why I thought it might be useful, to generate for an object for each "Candle" to save their individual properties and to make them editable.

```
    var candleAmount = 3;
for (var i=1; i <= candleAmount; i++) {
    $("#container #candles").append("<li><img src=''></img></li>");
    var Candle+i = [ "background":"+i+", "color":" - random - (ignore)" ]
    };
```

(please dont mind any failures in the code besides the "Candle+i", I'll figure it out.)

**EDIT:** Ok, thank you so far. I might not made myself clear enaugh. 
Here is an way more reduced example:

```
$("ul#candles li").each( function(i) {
  candle+i = i+" Anything";
  });

alert(candle4);
```

I would love to create an amount of variables depending on the Amount of child-objects.
What would be the correct syntax, or isn't there any?

Thank you

Comment: @see my update. Ps don't forget to mark as answer or upvote if you appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So is there any way, to generate object-names with an index?

Yes, in JavaScript, global variables are defined as properties of the global-object. (Inside a function, variables are defined as properties of the Activation object.) You can reference the global object by `window` (for browser applications) or just by `this`.

And because all objects are associative you can give there properties just the name you want. So, setting a global variable is equal to set a property into the global object.

```
var foo = "bar"; === this["foo"] = "bar";
```

Now, its just a small step to add a dynamic part to the name:

```
for(var i=0;i<10;i++) {
 this['candle' + i] = i;  
}

alert(candle7);
```

**For your specific code:**

```
$("ul#candles li").each( function(i) {
  window["candle" + i] = i+" Anything";
  });

alert(candle4);
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried to add the index to the variable-name, but it didn't work for me. I just added a more simple example to my post, maybe you can do your magic there?

Comment: The problem is now that you assign your variables from within a function. That makes that the variables are defined in the activation-object but only if you use var. I'll will make your code work, its a little much to explain it.

Answer (score 1):

just put them in an array and access them via index. Result is most likely the same for you and is much better than let them floating in your scope